# Adjusting the month being viewed on the Calendar Block to match the month of the Day being viewed

Tags: 7, blocks, datetime

So, I am using Drupal 7 with the Calendar Module. I am using the calendar block as the primary calendar for viewing events daily events. Everything works great, except the calendar block doesn't change its month being viewed to match the day being viewed.

For example. The calendar block is visible and starts at the month of November (because it is November). You browse to December and click on a day to view that day's events. The page loads and shows the events for that particular day in December, but the calendar block defaults back to November. I want it to show December since I am viewing a day in that month

Is there a way to have the calendar block show the month that matches the day being viewed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to set "track current date in session" under admin/config/date/calendar?

This should do the trick...

Comment: I figured it had to be something easy... Thanks so much!